# Finding All Combinations for a JavaScript String

Tags: javascript

I just read an interesting article [Bruce Schneier - Choosing Secure Passwords](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/choosing_secure_1.html) and came up with the idea of finding out how long it would take JavaScript to "crack" my own password (a string/ the function parameter).

How can I write a function, that simply compares all possible combinations of letters (and later numbers, maybe special characters etc.) with a certain input parameter (type is string) of that function. The possible characters will be listed in an array.

e.g.:

```
var letterDB = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
// actually I would like to use a Regular Expression instead of my own letterDB, but for the beginning it is fine.
```

I could find a solution for input parameters of only 1 letter (but I am still missing to pass longer strings into that function). It is very confusing how to handle the problem of strings like "cloud", "play", etc. I am thinking about solving this issue with a for-loop but I don't really know where to start with the loop and how I programm loops for inputs that I dont' know the length yet.

My function:

```
function crack(x) {
  var timerStart = Date.now();  //for curiosity I want to log the time of the entire calculation
  var s = String(x);            //make sure the input is of type string (gets interesting when numbers are used in the string)

  for(i=0; i < letterDB.length; i++) {
      if (s == letterDB[i]) {
          console.log("found same combination as your input");
          console.log("letter was: " + letterDB[i]);
          console.log("interval: " + i);
          console.log("calculation time:", Date.now() - timerStart);  //interesting to see the time of the calculation when my input parameters will get longer and harder to crack because of special characters.
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: These things take massive amounts of time to work, which makes them pointless to even try.  I'd suggest looking at dictionary attacks instead.  They're not as effective, but they're quicker.

Comment: Note that password cracking is usually done by generating an _entire_ password and seeing if it matches, rather than one character at a time, as the stored password _should_ be salted and hashed, and therefore it's impossible to check it a single character at a time as you appear to be attempting to do.  One character at a time will be a _lot_ quicker than trying to do the whole password.

Comment: You are right. But I am trying to improve my understanding of JavaScript functions and programming patterns in general. The way of thinking about the problem and forming the solution. I do however leave finding a practicable way of cracking passwords fast to the people at Crypto City.

Comment: You can simply loop through the string and forEach letter check if `letterDB.includes(char) === true;`

Comment: @GSWV It needs to be solved with a function and input parameter. e.g. crack("ocean") .... // logs calculation time: 2 minutes.

Comment: I guess the quickest way would be to go through your letterDB using `string.indexOf` on the string to crack (multiple times if necessary, to find duplicates). But to improve your js loop-writing skills, you need a very laborious set of nested loops, building up bigger and bigger strings. Which will take ages to run, but will be instructive.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldareak0/) with your approach.  Note that even with an 18 char password, it still executes in < 1ms.  To get any real world "seeing how long it will take to crack a password", you're going to have to try to do the whole thing in one go.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, this will take forever. However, it's relatively simple to implement a permutation-based cracker with recursion.

```
var input = "ad";
var done = false;
var maxLength = 2;
var letterDB = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

function recursion (str) {
   for (var i=0; i < letterDB.length; i++) {
      var test = str+letterDB[i];
      if (test !== input && !done && str.length < maxLength) {
         recursion(test);
      } else if (test === input) {
         done = true;
         alert("your pass is "+test);
      }
   }
}
recursion("");
```

To gauge how slow this is, the password `cloud` took me 33 seconds to find (with maxlength correctly set). The time would escalate extremely quickly for anything with a larger length.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the string and iterate over all the letters:

```
function crack(x) {
    var timerStart = Date.now();
    x = x.toString();
    var charsArr = s.split('');
    var result = charsArr.every(function(char) {
        return letterDB.includes(char);
    });
    if (result) {
        console.log("Success! calculation time:", Date.now() - timerStart);
    }
    console.log("fail");
    return result;
}
```

If result is true, then it means that you can build the string from the `letterDB` array.

Comment: I don´t think he is trying to check if the input is valid, he wants how long it would take to crack the input generating all possible permutations of strings